# Running .net application without user logging

Tags: .net

Can we have any mechanism other then window service by which we ensure that system tray application will run when no user is logged in? I am using .net to develop application and operating system is windows server 2003. Can we have any supporting middleware program which can support this?

Comment: Do you have an issue that prevents you from using services? It's certainly the standard way to persist processes across logins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't have a system tray icon running since the system tray doesn't exist when there is no user logged on. If you want to have it running all the time, a service is the only way to go.

If you want to notify the user of status of the service, the correct way is to create a small application that shwos the tray icon and communicates with the service. A simple way is to create a WCF service within your Windows Service and let the tray notification application connect to it.

Comment: If you think this was valuable, the "Stack Overflow way" is to upvote the answer. The best answer should be marked as accepted, but you can upvote any other answers that find find valuable as well.

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to do this is to write a Windows service. It starts up when the OS boots up and stays running until the OS shuts down or it is explicitly stopped by the service control manager.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a desktop without a logged in user, so you likewise can't have notification icons without a logged in user. A service is **the** answer-it's the way to run code that executes even when there is no user logged in.